# ASP.NET Core PageRequestManager Ajax Call equivalent

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, .net-core-2.2, pagerequestmanager

In ASP.NET Web forms we had access to Sys.PageRequestManager to determine the ajax call finish. How can we run a JS after ajax call finish in ASP.NET Core 2.2?
I do not have access the the Ajax call, it runs by a plugin, I have to write some code to make some changes to loaded data with that plagin ajax.

Comment: It looks like your question is all about the plugin and how to work with it, not asp.net stuff. Did you search for questions about the plugin?

Comment: No it's not, I said I don't have control on plugin itself, so I should try handling the issue myself, and the only event is ajax finished. Former in ASP.NET update panel we had access to pagerequestmanager, so we could handle ajax finishing, but in .NET core I don't know something line pagemanager